# Error response from daemon: can't create 'AutoRemove' container with restart policy

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

> Error response from daemon: can't create 'AutoRemove' container with restart policy

What does this error mean when I run the command:

```
docker compose run --rm api python3 manage.py migrate

...

 - Network saleor-platform_saleor-backend-tier  Created                                                                                                    1.6s
 - Network saleor-platform_default              Created                                                                                                    2.2s
 - Volume "saleor-platform_saleor-db"           Created                                                                                                    0.3s
 - Volume "saleor-platform_saleor-redis"        Created                                                                                                    0.2s
 - Volume "saleor-platform_saleor-media"        Created                                                                                                    0.4s
 - Container saleor-platform_db_1               Started                                                                                                   42.5s
 - Container saleor-platform_redis_1            Started                                                                                                   46.1s
 - Container saleor-platform_jaeger_1           Started                                                                                                   46.8s
Error response from daemon: can't create 'AutoRemove' container with restart policy
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error got resolved by **re-running** the previous command:

```
>docker-compose run --rm api python3 manage.py migrate
```

Not sure why **re-run** resolved the error. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a docker bug or misconfigured environment or what, but removing `--rm` fixes this error.